# Python import methods from directory into other directory

Tags: python, import, module

for some reason I don't achieve any progress in this simple question, and it makes me bonkers.

I'm working on the `odsrw` module inside of `src`. Inside the `odsrw` folder is `sqlite_data`, a submodule where I have created some functions to interact with my database. Now I need these functions inside my `main.py` in `odsrw`, so I created a `__init__.py` inside `sqlite_data`:

```
from .models import Players, Games, Highscores
from .db_functions import add_player, add_game, add_highscore
from .db_setup import create_session, db_session


__all__ = ['Players',
           'Games',
           'Highscores',
           'add_player',
           'add_game',
           'add_highscore',
           'create_session',
           'db_session']
```

I successfully imported them with this line into my `main.py`: `from sqlite_data import add_player, add_game, add_highscore`.

Now, I have to write tests for my `odsrw` and `sqlite_data` module. For that I tried to import the same methods which I imported in the `main.py` into my `tests/test_02.py`. But for some reason, nothing works. I can't import them with `src.odsrw.sqlite_data`, not with `src.odsrw.sqlite_data.db_functions` and not with `..src.odsrw.sqlite_data`.

Am I missing something vital? For the record, the two `__init__.py`'s in `src` and `odsrw` are empty, only the `__init__.py` in `sqlite_data` has written something in it.

I will also make a python package from the code, so I can someone give me input how to import the methods in a non-absolute way?

My file structure:

```
repository
├───src
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   └───odsrw
│       │   main.py
│       │   ods_extractor.py
│       │   __init__.py
│       │
│       ├───sqlite_data
│       │   │   db_functions.py
│       │   │   db_setup.py
│       │   │   models.py
│       │   │   __init__.py
│       │   │
│       │   └───__pycache__
│       │           db_functions.cpython-310.pyc
│       │           db_setup.cpython-310.pyc
│       │           models.cpython-310.pyc
│       │           __init__.cpython-310.pyc
│       │
│       └───__pycache__
│               main.cpython-310.pyc
│               ods_extractor.cpython-310.pyc
│               __init__.cpython-310.pyc
│
└───tests
        test_00.py
        test_01.py
        test_02.py
        __init__.py
```

Comment: first you need to install the library, which will add `src` to your `PYTHONPATH`, then you can just import it in tests using `import odsrw....`